# Unity3D: Adding force based on direction an object is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I am trying to make a "worms"-like game where the player can choose the position of an object (the player can move the object around 180 degrees) , and then the force would be added to the direction the object is facing. I tried using transform.right and transform.forward, but the force was not driven towards where the object is pointing. I have looked around A LOT, and still not found/understand what I can do. Heres the code I use for shooting the object:

```
    void shootIt(){
       transform.parent = null;
        isPlaying = true;
        A.isKinematic = false;
        A.AddForce(transform.up*varSpeed*_multiplier);
} //"A" stands for the RigidBody2D component I got by using GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

Help is as always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you rotate your object?

Comment: It does not rotate, but the object is moved around 180 degrees using localPosition of x,y and z axis using mathematical functions

Comment: Ah i see, well maybe you dont want to move it twoards its orientation. 1 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void shootIt()
{
    Vector2 direction = transform.localPosition.normalized;
    transform.parent = null;
    isPlaying = true;
    A.isKinematic = false;
    A.AddForce(direction*varSpeed*_multiplier);
}
```

Also consider forcing yourself to write good names for your variables. `A` is not very descriptive.

Comment: You just fixed a problem I have been trying to find for ages. I can not thank you enough.